# Using cut in a shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file name foo. That file contains some text (shown below). Can you please tell me how can I get the string "I have not created a home page." into a variable. I was using the command `variable='cat foo | cut -d ">" -f 3'`. It output "I have not created a home page." with lots of new lines in it. Please let me know if you can tell me a way to obtain the string without any newlines. Thanks a lot.

```
<HTML>

<HEAD> 
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="resource-type" CONTENT="document">
</HEAD>

<BODY>

I have not created a home page.

</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cat foo | grep "^[^<]"`. To assign a variable:

```
v=`cat foo | grep "^[^<]"`
```

Comment: This is vulnerable to any whitespace variation

Comment: This will match all non-empty lines that don't begin with `<`, including those that begin `space-<` (as an example of what MarcH is referring to).

Comment: Another useless use of cat. Just run `v=$(grep "^[^<]" foo)`. Saves about a million processor cycles for the useless fork, useless exec and useless reads and writes.

Answer (score 2):

cut is the wrong tool. Use awk:

```
cat >> _.awk << "EOF"
/<BODY>/               { found=1; next }
/<\/BODY>/ && found==1 { exit 0 }
found==1               { if ($1) print $0 }
EOF

awk -f _.awk foo
```

Ideally you should use a real XML parser like a DOM parser

Answer (score 1):

```
{ xmlstarlet sel -N html='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' -t -m //html:body -v . <(tidy -asxml input.html) | tr -d '\n' ; } 2> /dev/null
```